# Re fermentation

Tags: stuck-fermentation

I have 2, 6 gallon carboys, one apple & the other peach. The apple is bubbling really good, the peach not at all from what I have seen.
Can/should I add more yeast or sugar to kick start it?

Comment: We're gonna need a lot more information before we can assess what the problem is.  Is this a cider?  If so, what's your ingredients, what did you use for yeast?  What was your original gravity?  What was your process for extracting the juice?  How long have they been fermenting for.  The more thorough you are with your question, the better the odds are you'll get the answer you need.  Right now we'd just be guessing blindly.

Comment: I am new to this so I did not know about gravity. The mix is about two weeks now.

Comment: Again, I am new to this home brewing, I did not take a original gravity reading, but am going to do so tonight after getting the tool to do so. The ingredents used where sugar, peaches and a fruit yeast, we got the yeast at a local home brew supply shop. We placed the peaches into our buckets and let sit, per what we read. We then squeeze it through a chees cloth, it has been sitting like that almost two weeks now.  The apple wine we are trying to make, we started this about a week ago. That jug is perking away quite nice.

Comment: How much sugar and peaches did you add?  What kind of sugar and peaches did you use (if you have URLs to where we can read about them, all the better)?  Did you press/juice them?  Are they sitting in the carboy whole/sliced?  What is the exact provider and strand of yeast used (again, URLs would be helpful).  Again, the more detailed information you can provide regarding your ingredients, and the steps taken (step-by-step is ideal), the better we'll be able to help.

Comment: And definitely check the gravity when you get whichever tool you go with for measuring.  While there's insufficient information thus far to do anything other than speculate, there is always the possibility that it has fermented all the way already, however much it could.

Comment: @RLB do you have the exact bill of fermentables, water volumes, boil times (if any), etc? Maybe we could help you make an assumption about your original gravity?

Answer (score 1):

When you say bubble are you meaning the airlock? It could be an issue with the seal of the carboy. Sometimes there is a leak in the seal so the brew is "bubbling" (this happens with the CO2 escaping when the alcohol is being produced) but you just cant see it in the airlock. As the others say we will need more information to solve the issue for you but you can always try the brew and see if you can taste alcohol or just off fruit.

Comment: I agree - if you gently push the lid of the bucket, or squeeze the container, do you see bubbles in the airlock? if not then you have a leak somewhere.